# Image displays in Android Studio but not device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am learning Kotlin and Jetpack compose and following the tutorial on https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-add-images. The background image displays in the preview but when I run the app on an emulator or a physical device then the background image does not display.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.happybirthday

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.HappyBirthdayTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HappyBirthdayTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                )
                {
                    GreetingText(
                        message = "Happy Birthday Sam!",
                        from = "From Emma"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun GreetingText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = modifier)
        {
            Text(
                text = message,
                fontSize = 50.sp,
                lineHeight = 60.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            Text(
                text = from,
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .align(alignment = Alignment.End)

            )
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun GreetingImage(message: String, from: String) {
        val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
        Box (modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()) {
            Image(
                painter = image,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                alpha = 0.5F
            )
            GreetingText(
                message = message,
                from = from,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(8.dp)
            )
        }
    }


    @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun BirthdayCardPreview() {
        HappyBirthdayTheme {
            GreetingImage(
                message = "Happy Birthday Sam!",
                from = "From Emma"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the image is not showing on a device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `@Preview` function, you're calling the `GreetingImage` function, but in the `OnCreate` function, you're only calling the `GreetingText` function. Instead, you need to call the `GreetingImage` function within the OnCreate function.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        HappyBirthdayTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            )
            {
                GreetingImage(
                    message = "Happy Birthday Sam!",
                    from = "From Emma"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks so just to understand this better. Everything you create as composables you have to repeat in the onCreate function?

Comment: No, screen's start point is onCreate method. @Preview annotation is just allow us to see and check UI on Android studio editor.